# factorring K[X]/(f)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $f\in K[X]$ with $\text{deg}(f)=n$, $K$ a field, I want to know something about $K[X]/(f)$. If $f\in K[X]$ is not irreducible and if you can write $f=(X-a)*h$, $h\in K[X]$ irreducible and $a\in K$, is $K[X]/(f)=K[X]/(h)$ true? 
Now we assume that $f\in K[X]$ with $\text{deg}(f)=n$ and f is irreducible. Why is $K[X]/(f)$ the same as $\{g\in K[x]; \text{deg}(g)<n\}$? You can prove this with the euclidean algorithm, but I don't know how in detail..My thoughts are: $h\in K[X]/(f)$, you can write $h=t+s*f$ with $t,s\in K[X]$ (we assume here that $h \notin (f)$). If you apply the Euclidean algorithm on $h, f$ there exists $s,t\in K[X]$ polynomials such that $h=t+s*f$ and $\text{deg}(t)< \text{deg}(f)$. So you get $\{g\in K[x]; \text{deg}(g)<n\}$. 
 But my argument is poorly structured.

Answer (score 1):

With regard to your first question, *no*. In fact, by the CRT, since $(x-a)$ and $h(x)$ are coprime in $K[x]$,
\begin{equation*}
  K[x]/(f) = K[x]/((x-a)h(x)) \cong K[x]/(x-a) \times K[x]/(h)
     \cong K\times K[x]/h.
\end{equation*}
Your proof of the second point is fine; since $\text{deg}\ t < \text{deg}\ f$, you have shown what you want to show. Another way to look at it is that if you define a map from $K[x]$ to $\{g\in K[x]: \text{deg}(g) < n\}$ taking $h\mapsto t$, then the fiber over a given element of $\{g\in K[x]: \text{deg}(g) < n\}$ consists of $g+sf$ where $s$ ranges over all elements of $K[x]$; this is just $g+(f)$. (By the way, this set is actually a field under polynomial addition and multiplication modulo $f$).

Comment: The fiber $\,f^{-1}(\{g\}) = g + f K[x],\,$ not $\,fK[x].\,$ And $\,K[x]\,$ mod $\,f\,$ is a field, not $\,K[x]\,$ mod $\,x^n\ \ $